# What is the library for sql ExecuteScalar()

Tags: c#, sql

I get the error that SQLConnection has no Definition for ExecuteScalar...

Fehler  CS1061  "SqlConnection" enthält keine Definition für "ExecuteScalar", und es konnte keine zugängliche ExecuteScalar-Erweiterungsmethode gefunden werden, die ein erstes Argument vom Typ "SqlConnection" akzeptiert (möglicherweise fehlt eine using-Direktive oder ein Assemblyverweis)

So what is the problem here or yeah how to fix it.

```
// Check if entry exists
SqlConnection con = new SqlConnection(connectionstring);
con.Open();
string query = "SELECT COUNT(KNR) FROM AuswertungDurchlaufzeit WHERE KNR = '" + WNR_KNR[1] + "'";
SqlCommand cmd = new SqlCommand(query, con);
cmd.ExecuteNonQuery();
Int32 count = (Int32)con.ExecuteScalar();
con.Close();
// if return=1 -> UPDATE 
// else new entry -> INSERT
if (count > 0)
{
    return;
}
else
{}
```

Comment: You should use SQLCommand Object

Comment: And use SQLParameters. You are probably vulnerable to SQL Injection.

Comment: And another suggestion: try and post english versions / translations of error messages. I happen to be German speaking but most users may be not.

Comment: Side note: it seems you are looking for `upsert`: insert new record if and only if the table doesn't contain such one.

Comment: When query with `SELECT` you want to return some data; `ExecuteScalar` or `ExecuteReader` but not `cmd.ExecuteNonQuery();`

Comment: `Int32 count = Convert.ToInt32(cmd.ExecuteScalar());` do **not** cast command `con` to int

Answer (score 0, accepted):

`ExecuteNonQuery` is used for SQL statements with no results. It is used to execute the SQL statements like UPDATE, INSERT, DELETE etc..

You have tried this `cmd.ExecuteNonQuery();` In your code, you are not doing any operation like this in your code. It is therefore not needed.

`ExecuteScalar` method is used to execute SQL Commands. It should execute the command statements by `SqlCommand`.

Instead of `cmd` you used `con` object.

You can try the following code:

```
using (SqlConnection con = new SqlConnection(connectionstring))
{
    con.Open();
    var sqlQuery = string.Format("SELECT COUNT(KNR) FROM AuswertungDurchlaufzeit WHERE KNR = '{0}'", WNR_KNR[1]);                   
    SqlCommand cmd = new SqlCommand(sqlQuery, con);                    
    Int32 count = (Int32)cmd.ExecuteScalar();
    cmd.Dispose();
    con.Close();
    // if return=1 -> UPDATE 
    // else new entry -> INSERT
    if (count > 0)
    {
        return;
    }
    else
    { }
}
```

Comment: Thanks, @Alexander for the proper text arrangement :)